# Can't pass an array of slugs to friendly_id finder (friendly_id 4.0 stable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, friendly-id

Is it not possible to do the following with friendly_id 4.0 stable?

```
Post.find('slug-1', 'slug-2')
```

I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do that, since FriendlyId uses `where(...).first` query internally.